# VBA, Email, ActiveX Component can't create object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run an automatic email via VBA.

However I get the error `ActiveX Component can't create object`

on this line of code:

```
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.14")
```

Typically another person runs this code on their computer and works fine.

What is causing the activex error?

Comment: Are you running Outlook at the same time you are running the code? [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/run-time-error-429-activex-component-cant-create/c487d430-1348-4123-a527-00a9a9f4a424?msgId=303f2ba1-c6b2-4f60-8011-98dd7054497e)

Comment: Yes, outlook is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try removing the `14`:

```
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Also, per @JosephC's note, you might need Outlook to be open

Comment: Thanks kubie, looks like removal of the 14 worked for me.